# Magento: Directly output any errors or notices

Tags: debugging, magento, magento-1.7

In my module's code, I echo'd an undefined variable:

```
echo $doesnotexist;
```

I have done the following in **index.php**:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This combination shows a "Whoops, our bad..." 404 type page when the code is executed. And in the *exception.log* there is a Notice ("*Undefined variable: doesnotexist*") as well as a stack trace.

If I remove part of the instructions in **index.php**:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The frontend shows the page normally without any indication of the error, and the error is logged to *system.log*.

Now my question is: Is there a way to output these notices/errors directly to the frontend? Or  am I supposed to always keep open a copy of *system.log* or *exception.log* while coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento normally uses zend exception/error handling class for the error and exception handling. So for the errors in which magento code send exception is logged in your log. 
But if the error is not catchable  by magento then it will be printed on your page.

You can get your error on frontend in 2 case:

1. If you are creating your own magento extension then you can throw your error in the way so that it can get displayed on magento page
2. If you are working on .phtml file and getting fatal errors

Answer (score 0):

1. As a security concern errors and warning s should not be displayed on front end.
2. If there is an exception or you do some system log you will be able to get that from system.log or exception.log
3. For PHP errors you should refer to error log file that is generated at site level.
4. Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); can be used only after you have included Mage.php so paste your complete index.php code